# Migration from 1.9.1.0 to 2.0 ignore few tables

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

This is the error I am getting while migrating Magento 1.9.1.0 to Magento 2.0

```
[2016-01-10 17:16:02][ERROR]: Source documents are missing or not mapped: 
xmlconnect_application,
xmlconnect_config_data,
xmlconnect_history,
xmlconnect_images,
xmlconnect_notification_template,
xmlconnect_queue
```

When I look both the Magento databases I understand that these tables are only exist in 1.9.1.0 but not in 2.0 and thats the reason its throwing error.

How can I exclude or ignore these tables?

Answer (score 2):

Found the way by adding them in map.xml file under document_rules.

```
        <ignore>
            <document>xmlconnect_application</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <document>xmlconnect_config_data</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <document>xmlconnect_history</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <document>xmlconnect_images</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <document>xmlconnect_notification_template</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
            <document>xmlconnect_queue</document>
        </ignore>
```

Comment: Just need to add the custom table name inside the document tag as below?

`code`<ignore>
      <document>custom_table_name</document>
</ignore>`code`